# Sort documents in a collection firestore by document ID

Tags: firebase, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection where I'm storing different chapters in documents, like chapter 1 in a document, chapter 2 in another document and so on.

I want to store these documents in the descending order. I want Chapter 500 to be displayed first, followed by chapter 499 and so on.

I found a similar question, but that was sorting based on a value present in each document. I want the sorting to be done from the document name itself. (The document names are 'Chapter 1', 'Chapter 2' and so on). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your document names are formatted like "Chapter 1" and "Chapter 111", then what you're doing isn't possible.  Strings don't sort like numbers.  Note the sort order of these two strings:

1. "Chapter 11"
2. "Chapter 9"

Note that 11 comes before 9 here, because the character 1 sorts [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) before character 9, and it doesn't matter what other numbers come after the 1 in the first string.

I strongly suggesting considering using an actual number field in the document for the sort.